Minimum path cost of a directed weighted graph with cycles maximizing the number of visited nodes
Couldn't find any similar question asked before so here I go:
I'm working with JAVA but any pseudo-code will be more than welcome.
Given:

Graph G directed, weighted and with cycles.
Set of V vertices.
Set of E edges.
Initial node.
Final node.

I want to achieve the following:

An algorithm capable of computing the minimum cost path with maximum number of vertices in the graph for every node.

The function result should be a map, with the vertex ID as key and the cost as value.
In the image attach you can see an example:


There is a loop in your graph.  What can't you go around that loop as many times as you want?  What is A' that appears out of nowhere?

Indeed, there is a loop, thats a big part of the issue here. The thing is to find the largest path (maximizing number of nodes visited) but limiting with the minimum cost posible. So it translates to, the shortest path visiting all posible nodes. About A' is basically that the graph has 2 constraints, an initial and final node, which implies that all paths have to start from A and finish in A. I wrote A' to understand that it is also the final stop, apologies for not making that clear! Salut
